# Accessing data with use of composite key

Tags: mysql, composite-key

I seem to have an issue with understanding how to use the composite key. Setting one up seems to be ok. But, cannot find an example on how to use it.

My thinking would be there is an option to say i.e. 
`select * from tableA where primary_key = something`
without going into details if it’s a single primary key or a composite.

MySQL is spewing out information about duplicate composite key by concatenating it. So for example composite key is made of those columns: (id_company_subsid, id_company, id_subsidiary, company_subsidiary_start) and so composite key is printed out as:

`Duplicate entry '92078-2706-6552-2010-12-31' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Is it possible for query to be build in a similar way? I.e. `select * from tableA where primary_key = '92078-2706-6552-2010-12-31'` and MySQL would figure out how to use it? It’ll match it up against all columns from preset composite key?

**Edit/Clarification:**
Solution to this problem is meant to be used in automated software were tables with same schema are compared against each other. Tables with various primary keys (some single, some composite). Tables come as they are.

Each table has added a column with a hashed value of all other columns within the row. This is used for comparison between tables.

The goal is to inner join two tables by their two columns (primary key + hash column) to fish out the differences between.

Comment: How does your schema look like?

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at but a composite key is a key made up of many columns. You cannot refer to this in a query and the primary_key you refer to in the question is a column which could be made up of many other columns and 'keyed'

Comment: *"Is it possible for query to be build in a similar way?"* Sounds like your are looking for a [Generated Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) ? As you can use CONCAT() to concatenate the columns togther, index it. and you can use the generated column in the WHERE clause to filter

Comment: Have updated (clarified) question and the goal i'm trying to achieve. Is it bit clearer now?

Comment: (its also possible that a table does not have a primary key)

Comment: '92078-2706-6552-2010-12-31' and MySQL would figure out how to use it - If your question is could mysql figure out a match if the nodes were in a different order then no mysql cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @spencer7593 comments to his answer. It appears my goal cannot be achieved in this manner. Each of primary keys columns must be addressed individually.

@spencer7593 clarifying comment:

> @Rob: no, not in the context of a MySQL query to retrieve a row based on the value of the columns in the primary key, no – spencer7593 Jun 14 at 15:25

Answer (score 0):

Just include a condition on each individual column, something like this:

```
SELECT ....
  FROM t
 WHERE t.fee = '92078'
   AND t.fi  = '2706'
   AND t.fo  = '6552'
   AND t.fum = '2010-12-31'
```

---

There is no mechanism to specify a condition on the "primary key" or a "unique key" or any "key" for that matter. Table consists of columns, refer to the columns.

We can use expressions which reference columns. We could create an expression like this:

```
CONCAT(t.fee,'-',t.fi,'-',t.fo,'-',t.fum)
```

But we wouldn't want to use an equality comparison on that expression in the WHERE clause, because that wouldn't be able to make efficient use of an index; that would force MySQL to evaluate that expression for every row in the table.

Comment: So, if a primary key (composite) is set on multiple columns it is not possible to refer to it as a single entity?

Comment: @Rob: no, not in the context of a MySQL query to retrieve a row based on the value of the columns in the primary key, no